# How to add a "driver" to javax.comm? Serial port programming in Java

Tags: java, serial-port, javax.comm

I am trying to use a RS-232 serial port on my PC with javax.comm class. I am newby on that API, so first of all I go through the documentation and I find out that the first thing you should do is "list" all the ports from the class CommPortListener and pick up one of them.

That worked just fine! Problem is, now, that my port is missing. It lists the /dev/ttyS0 and /dev/ttyS1 ports, non existents on my computer. My ports (I have been working with them several times) are /dev/ttySNX0 and /dev/ttySNX1.

Again surfing the web I find out that I should do something like "register" or "load" the driver of my card onto the API system, stuff that could be done in previous versions, but not now. Moreover, I tried to do it under windows and they offer me a "generic" version of the API, with needs some RXTX application which is starting to beat me.

I would thank any sugestions, links to documentation... something... that allow me to use my serial ports through Java, wich, in the end, is my objective...

Thanks folks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried RXTX?  I've had successf with that API on Windows/XP.  I'n not sure what you mean by "starting to beat me".

There has been a lot of recent activity on the RXTX project and a new release incorporating a number of fixes and additional support is imminent.  The mailing list is also relatively active. `javax.comm` has been more or less dead for a while.